# Using jquery to replace a <br> with a space

Tags: jquery, replace

I'm importing a facebook RSS feed and many of the posts are missing a title. So in that case I want to pull some content from the body and use it as the title. The problem is that the body content can look like this...

```
Lorem ipsum<br>www.youtube.com<br>dolor sit amet.
```

I can't simply remove the br tags because it will become a run on sentence. I would rather replace the tags with a single space or comma with a space. I've tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
$('.teaser-title br').replaceWith(' ');
```

Thoughts?

Comment: `$('.teaser-title br').remove()` perhaps?

Comment: I have succesfully tested this code. Does `.teaser-title` select the correct element? What browser/jQuery version are you using?

Comment: @JamWaffles I can't just remove it because it will become a run-on sentence.

Comment: @RobW You can see the live page here http://www.wildcat.drupion.com/

Notice the second post's title has br's included. The page includes the JS http://www.wildcat.drupion.com/sites/default/themes/versatile/js/convert-title-br-tag-to-space.js

Running Jquery 1.5.2

Comment: @BryanCasler Of course. I didn't think this through enough. Sorry!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Description

2 Possible problems

1. You have no element with the class `teaser-title`.
2. You don't wait till the DOM is fully buildt

Anyway, this works

#### Sample

```
<div class="teaser-title">
    Lorem ipsum<br>www.youtube.com<br>dolor sit amet.
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
   $('.teaser-title br').replaceWith(' ');
});
</script>
```

## Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R9WP3/)

Comment: Turned out to be #2. I enabled LABjs and it's now executing properly. Combined this with @loktar's CSS solution to help prevent a bit of browser jump. It also helps if the user has JS disabled.

Answer (score 6):

Posting because it can be done! Could use CSS :P

(only works in webkit, so not really recommended)

```
.teaser-title br{
    content:"";
}

.teaser-title br:after{
   content:" ";
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/HDbKY/)**

Comment: dont ruin it @roXon :P *checks in other browsers* ok.. appears to only work in webkit.

Comment: This works great combined with the other solutions! Helps prevent a bit of browser jump!

Comment: @Bryan Casler, We've wait too long to see IE6 die, now you have to be patient to see that happen to IE7 too.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    $(".teaser-title br").replaceWith("&nbsp;");
});
```

Comment: You're missing a close parenthesis somewhere.  A bit of explanation would be nice too.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't simply remove the br tags because it will become a run on sentence.

Since you're worried about run on sentences, you can replace the `<br>`s with `<wbr>`s.

[HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/wbr.html) describes `<wbr>` thus:

> The `wbr` element represents a line-break opportunity.

Comment: This is awesome! It's not the most backwards compatible solution, but it's great to know. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to replace the element, and you have to replace only the innerHtml of the .teaser-title, if .teaser-title is your container element.

try this

```
var container = $(".teaser-title").html();
var regex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
$(".teaser-title").html(container.replace(regex, " "));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace the contents as text, not as tags:

```
$('.teaser-title').html($('.teaser-title').html().replace(/<br />/g,' '))
```

Comment: I think the `/` after `br ` needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well.
Here is just another way:

```
$('.teaser-title br').after(' ').remove();
//$('.teaser-title br').replaceWith(' '); // your solution works too!
```

## [demo](http://jsbin.com/abozek/edit#javascript,html,live)

Comment: Is there a benefit of .after over .replaceWith?